# How can I add separators between different records in a bincoded file?

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization, serde

I have following `struct`

```
struct Employee {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
}
```

I am serializing it with following code and then writing the serialized byte array to a file:

```
let emp = Employee {
    id: 1546,
    name: "abcd".to_string(),
};

let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
    .read(true)
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .open("hello.txt")
    .unwrap();

let initial_buf = &bincode::serialize(&emp).unwrap();

println!("Initial Buf: {:?}", initial_buf);

file.write(&initial_buf);
file.write(&[b'\n']);
file.flush();

file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0)).unwrap();

let mut final_buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut final_buf).unwrap();

println!("Final Buf: {:?}", final_buf);
```

I get the following output:

```
Initial Buf: [10, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 97, 98, 99, 100]
Final Buf: [10]
```

Comment: The newline (ascii `10`) is in `initial_buf`, so it seems clear that it's originating from `serialize`, which you haven't provided.

Comment: `serialize` is `bincode::serialize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bincode's contract is that you give it a value to serialize and it gives you back bytes. The contract does not guarantee that the bytes you get back cannot contain a newline.

In your data the integer 1546 is 0x60A which is represented as the bytes `[10, 6, 0, 0]`.

You should be able to work with Bincode data without any separators at all. The [`bincode::deserialize_from`](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.0/bincode/fn.deserialize_from.html) function will know where to stop reading.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the virtual cursor in file can be at any place. For example, if I want to read a random record from the middle of file, how can I seek to the starting location of that record? To accomplish this, I'll have to store the starting offsets of all the records separately.

Comment: If you require the ability to seek, you could length-prefix each record. Generally I would expect this approach to be significantly more efficient than using a newline delimiter -- because in order to seek to a particular "line" of the file you need to look at every single byte before that line to determine whether it is a newline byte, whereas with length prefixes you can skip an entire record with one read.

Comment: Also, it would be great if somehow we can add this in bincode itself. BSON adds int32 at the beginning to specify the length of encoded byte array.